# SubSonic.SqlQuery ExecuteTypedList<T> returning new objects only

Tags: c#, asp.net, subsonic

I am using SubSonic in my project. I need to selected rows filtered by some condition. I'm trying to use SqlQuery as follows:

```
            SqlQuery q = new Select()
           .From("TableName")
           .Where(MyDALObject.Columns.Status)
           .NotIn(new[] { 1, 8, 9,  22, 23});

           IList<MyDALObject> list =     
              q.ExecuteTypedList<MyDALObject>();
```

but all the objects in *list* List are new. What is wrong?

Comment: Actually I got the problem. I'm initing my BLL objects with DAL objects. and when you use SqlQuery the objects returned has IsNew set to true (strangely). I'm checking in ctor if dalObj.IsNew then init it with fresh object and that is problem. So I'm  closing the question. once again MY CODE WAS FAULTY NOT SUBSONIC'S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
MyDALObjectCollection = new Select()
  .From(MyDALObject.Schema)
  .Where(MyDALObject.Columns.Status).NotIn(new[] { 1, 8, 9,  22, 23})
  .ExecuteAsCollection<MyDALObjectCollection>();
```

Comment: Great @Adam this is nice. Actually I got the problem. I'm initing my BLL objects with DAL objects. and when you use SqlQuery the objects returned has IsNew set to true (strangely). I'm checking in ctor if dalObj.IsNew then init it with fresh object and that is problem.